# Maui Blazor - CS0029 when passing component @ref

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-blazor

After updating Visual Studio to version 17.6.0, the following error occurred in my MAUI project:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ElementReference' to '<componentName>'

[image]

---

Here is my code:

```
@using UI.Components.Dialogs.InfoDialog
@using UI.Components.Dialogs.InputDialog
@using UI.Components.Dialogs.MessageDialog
@using UI.Components.Dialogs.SettingsDialog
@using UI.Components.Dialogs.ProcedureTypeSelectorDialog
@using UI.Services;

@inject DialogService dialogService

<InputDialog @ref="inputDialog" />
<InfoDialog @ref="infoDialog" />
<MessageDialog @ref="messageDialog" />
<SettingsDialog @ref="settingsDialog" />
<ProcedureTypeSelectorDialog @ref="procedureTypeSelectorDialog" />

@code {
    InputDialog inputDialog { set => dialogService.RegisterDialog(value); }
    InfoDialog infoDialog { set => dialogService.RegisterDialog(value); }
    MessageDialog messageDialog { set => dialogService.RegisterDialog(value); }
    SettingsDialog settingsDialog { set => dialogService.RegisterDialog(value); }
    ProcedureTypeSelectorDialog procedureTypeSelectorDialog { set => dialogService.RegisterDialog(value); }
}
```

I have tried the following:

1. Transfer everything to the codebehind
2. Remove the duplication of the namespace and the name of the component (in fact, I pulled the components from their folders)
3. I was looking for ways to convert `ElementReference` or extract my component from it (I didn't find anything like that)
4. Deleted folders .vs, bin, obj and rebuilt the project

Before updating Visual Studio (I was working on version 17.5), this code worked fine. After the update, when trying to run with the same code, I encountered this error. Thank you all in advance for your help!

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: I gave the error message in text form, added a picture for completeness :)

Comment: Same problem here, after update i can't use element as reference

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It seems to happen when trying to do a `@ref` on a component that `@inherits` anything - even inheriting a totally blank class triggers it. I think this problem needs reporting to MS, and in the meantime, it's best to roll back the Visual Studio version.

Comment: OK, in the near future I will write to them in Gh using the links from the answer. Indeed, the components in the markup are inherited from another component

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue on the new version of Visual Studio 17.6.0. I recommend you to report it as a [new issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues) on the GitHub and report a [problem with the Visual Studio product](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) for more information.

Comment: I also have same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76286911/error-cs0029-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-components-el

Answer (score 1):

move the imports to _Imports.razor