# error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ElementReference' to x with MS Build 16.1 and VS 2022 17.6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor-server-side

I get this error: "`error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ElementReference' to MyComponent` only when building inside docker. It is BLazor .NET Core 7 application. I can copy all the code, but strange thing is that there are no errors or warnings inside Visual Studio. Also when I manually run "dotnet build -c Release" it works without errors.

This is part of dockerfile:

```
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
  WORKDIR /src
  COPY ["MyProject.csproj", "MyProject/"]

   RUN dotnet restore "MyProject.csproj" --source "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json;
   COPY . .
  WORKDIR "/src/MyProject"
   RUN dotnet build "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

   FROM build AS publish
   RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

   FROM base AS final
   WORKDIR /app
   COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

   ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]
```

**This happens also locally after upgrading to Visual Studio 17.6 (from 17.5.5)**

Comment: Microsoft is aware of the issue. It is tracked by: https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/8727